# how to load api response data as translation in React-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

i am trying to fetch the translation data from the api response using the following code snippet and the api call is success -

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from './utils/Url';



const loadResources = async (locale) => {
    let contUrl = BASE_URL + '/translation';
    return await axios
        .post(contUrl, {
            lang: 'fr-ca',

            type: 'json',

            location: 'msdemo',

            country: 'CA',
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.translation_data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

const backendOptions = {
    loadPath: '{{lng}}|{{ns}}',
    request: (options, url, payload, callback) => {
        try {
            const [lng] = url.split('|');
            loadResources(lng).then((response) => {
                console.log('response', response);
                callback(null, {
                    data: response,
                    status: 200,
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            callback(null, {
                status: 500,
            });
        }
    },
};



i18n.use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(Backend)
    .init({
        backend: backendOptions,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        load: 'languageOnly',
        ns: ['translations'],
        defaultNS: 'translations',
        keySeparator: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
            formatSeparator: ',',
        },
        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    });


export default i18n;
```

the response of the translate api is following -->

```
{
   .......,
   .......,
  "Verify": "Vérifier",
  "WELCOME": "BIENVENUE",
  "ewallet": "Portefeuille électronique",
  "testing": "Test"
}
```

it looks like the translations are even loaded , it logs the following in console

[image: log]

but when i am trying to translate using 't' function , it's not working .

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
....
..
t('Verify')
```

output is 'Verify' i.e key , it should be the translated value i.e "Vérifier"

Comment: you may show how you're using the t function?

Comment: sure, can you please check now

Comment: Are there more debug logs? Is there something like missing key? Is it possible you're not using Suspense? https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense

Comment: no there are no more debug logs , I have tried with Suspense , still facing the same issue.

Comment: a minimal reproducible example repository or codesandbox would help to investigate